# Distributing $n$ identical item to $k$ groups, each group must have at least one item

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The problem is formulated as distributing $n$ pennies to $k$ children and each child is guaranteed at least one penny. The theorem is given as $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ but I don't understand this theorem. The explanation is pretty brief.

My thought was that we take $k$ pennies from $n$, and distribute the pennies to each group. So now we are left with $n-k$ pennies, and distribute $n-k$ pennies to $k$ children so the answer is $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways to distribute them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be specified that the pennies are indistinguishable but the children  are unique individuals, so that outcomes differ accordingly as to the number of pennies received by each child.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [stars and bars](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

The idea is that we can line the children's pennies up with each child's pennies together like this

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cc|cccc|c}
\circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \end{array}$$

Where the first group belongs to the first child, the second group belongs to the second child and so on.

Then each child has a penny since each child gets at least one penny, so consider the first penny for each child (numbered below).

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cc|cccc|c}
1 & \circ & \circ &
2 & \circ &
3 & \circ & \circ & \circ &
4 \end{array}$$

Notice that in order to divide all these pennies, it is sufficient to pick which penny is each child's first penny and give them all the pennies from that point to the next penny picked. i.e. we can go from this picture:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & \circ & \circ &
2 & \circ &
3 & \circ & \circ & \circ &
4 \end{array}$$

to this picture:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cc|cccc|c}
1 & \circ & \circ &
2 & \circ &
3 & \circ & \circ & \circ &
4 \end{array}$$

Note that the first child always has the first penny in the line, but then we are free to choose the other $k-1$ children's first pennies from the $n-1$ remaining pennies. This gives $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to distribute the pennies.

Comment: Ooooh, i think i understand this now. Since the first child already has the penny, n-1 is distributed among the other k-1; so the other k-1 is also guaranteed at least one pennies. Thank you. I've been thinking about this all day, and google keep bring up binomial distribution instead of stars and bars.

Comment: @bushiebrownie I'm not sure I understood what you just said, but I'm glad I was helpful!

Comment: @jgon "then each child... least one penny." Could you make that part a little clearer? I got the meaning, but only after I read it thrice or so :)

Comment: @shardulc sure. Thanks for the feedback, give me a second.

Comment: @shardulc Edited.